# Why do tendons require over 100 days to make new collagen?

Tags: human-biology

{1} says:

> Tendons require over 100 days to make new collagen.

Why does it take so long for tendons to make new collagen?

---

References:

- {1} Bass, L. M. T. "Tendinopathy: why the difference between tendinitis and tendinosis matters." International Journal of Therapeutic Massage & Bodywork: Research, Education, & Practice 5.1 (2012): 14-17. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3312643/